# Issue with AWS EC2 instance on private subnet denied access for specific users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

We implement and attach the following IAM policy to certain users' groups to allow them to launch EC2 instances, create AMI, and launch AMI from them.

Our new problem is that these users are not able to launch private EC2 instances, but they are able to launch new instances in the public subnet.

```
policy ::

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateImage",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceTypes",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Error**: `You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: nYPzkz-yJvXNEUDaBE4_mLXT`

```
"DecodedMessage": "{"allowed":false,"explicitDeny":false,"matchedStatements":{"items":[]},"failures":{"items":[]},"context":{"principal":{"id":"","name":"","arn":""},"action":"iam:PassRole","resource":"arn:aws:iam:::role/ABC-CDE-webserver","conditions":{"items":[{"key":"aws:Region","values":{"items":[{"value":"us-east-1"}]}},{"key":"aws:Service","values":{"items":[{"value":"ec2"}]}},{"key":"aws:Resource","values":{"items":[{"value":"role/ABC-CDE-webserver"}]}},{"key":"iam:RoleName","values":{"items":[{"value":"ABC-CDE-webserver"}]}},{"key":"aws:Type","values":{"items":[{"value":"role"}]}},{"key":"aws:Account","values":{"items":[{"value":""}]}},{"key":"aws:ARN","values":{"items":[{"value":"arn:aws:iam:::role/ABC-CDE-webserver"}]}}]}}}
```

I still cannot figure out the problem; what is the issue? Is there anything that needs to be changed with this IAM policy

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You can check the encoded message on the CLI with ```aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message nYPzkz-yJvXNEUDaBE4_mLXT```. You will need permission for the ```sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage``` action to run this command. The decoded message should give more context on your problem.

Comment: An interesting mystery! How are the users launching the instance? Are they doing it via the EC2 console, or the AWS CLI? It is possible that a parameter is being passed that is causing the problem (eg do they have `iam:PassRole` permission), but it is not obvious what parameters would change simply by selecting a different subnet? I would recommend attempting the launch from the AWS CLI (`aws ec2 run-instances`) so that you have complete control over the parameters passed, and you can just change the `--subnet` parameter to debug the situation. Is it still failing when launched from the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

This update to the IAM policy has resolved my issue by allowing IAM users to create AMI and launch private instances from those AMIs. This policy provides the permissions necessary to complete this action using the AWS Console or AWS CLI.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:ImportSnapshot",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:CopySnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateImage",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceTypes",
                "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
                "ec2:DescribeIamInstanceProfileAssociations",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"

            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```